# Why is compiler constant sometimes named "SYSCONF_LINK" in C++ Makefiles?

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm just curious what "SYSCONF_LINK" means and why people use this constant name instead of "COMPILER", "CC" or something else like that.

Comment: Isn't it coming from Qt/qmake world?

Comment: I've seen it in projects that don't use anything but g++ and make.

Comment: I'll take qmake back. Looks like it might come from tmake, which was qmake ancestor, and it was generic meta-make tool (like cmake or qmake) a while ago

Comment: Because they chose to call it that. You could call it "FRED" for all `make` cares, as long as your compiling rule then also looked like `$(FRED) $(FREDFLAGS) -o .....`...

Comment: @twalberg I know I could — but in this particular case it's too widespread and specific to be a coincidence